# Logo design: what is this style called?

Tags: logo, shapes, style-identification, trends

I see many 'crystallized' style logos, for example the Sketch logo or something like the attached. What is this design style called?

[image: low poly]

Comment: There's not really one term. It could be "geometric", "low poly", "design only using triangles", etc.

Comment: @Zach That's almost and answer--that's my roundabout way of asking not to answer questions in the comments :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific name (like minimalism or skeuomorph). You can find this type of design by a category name.

[image: Example image of result for low poly logo]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 terms that describe this artwork:

> **Flat Low Poly**
>
> A search on Youtube brings similar results to your example.
>   https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=flat+low+poly+logo
>
> Here is another example of it being called "Low poly."
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3NoCw43fb0

_

> **Flat Geometric Design**
>
> This Youtube video shows a similar result and calls it a flat design
>   geometric pattern.
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sj7n0c_--eQ

Answer (score 1):

Bill Gardner, a logo designer and the creator of the website [LogoLounge](https://www.logolounge.com/), publishes an annual review of the trends in logo design that he has identified over the course of the past year.  [In 2008](https://www.logolounge.com/articles/2008-logo-trends), he identified a trend that he called "Facets." Here are the examples he provided:

[image]

In his [2014 trend report](https://www.logolounge.com/articles/2014-logo-trends), he includes "Flat Facets"

[image]

His 2014 description of the trend reads, in part:

> Another equally prolific line of trends over the last few years has been the facet. Watching this particular technique rocket and split into a variety of interpretations embraced by the design community has proven it has legs. This year's report identified four emerging strains, including Facet Fields, Crystals, Type Facets and Flat Facets, which we'll expound on here.

I think the terms "Facets," or "Crystals" probably best fit the images you linked in your question, but you could also investigate the other terms he uses in the quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

In the arts it is simply called "geometric" shapes, the simplicity of the overall look is called "minimalism"...if you go on google and simply search for those 2 you'll find a bunch more like it.

Comment: can you add examples that back up your answer? We tend to stay away from "one-liners" on this site.

Answer (score 0):

It's "low poly" , minimalism can be everything and a list of combination of every logo type doesn't help you. search for "low poly" and your happy

Answer (score 0):

It's typically called "geometric" design but can also be referred to as "low poly" because of it's roots in game design.

Answer (score -5):

There are a few basic styles.. those land more in the Combination Marks since they have a symbol and text.

Wordmarks = Text/Words in a certain typestyle
[image]

Lettermarks = Also words, but typically just Initials

[image]

Letterform marks = Logos in shapes of letters
[image]

Brandmarks/Pictorial = Symbols
[image]

Combination Marks = Text and Symbol
[image]

Emblem/Conceptual = Shape or abstract in the form of something recognizable 
[image]

Comment: Very good response, but I'm afraid it doesn't answer the question...